# Dryer & Stove share breakers in 1972 apt

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, subpanel, dryer

Question1: Why would one hot from the stove be wired into the dryer breaker and one hot from the dryer be wired into the stove breaker? Each has a separate neutral and both are grounded with their individual FMC metal flex conduits to the subpanel (no separate grounding wire).

Question2: Why is the dryer wired into a 40Amp breaker?

I opened up the 125Amp subpanel in apartment. I was shocked to see that one hot, black, from the stove, into the 50Amp breaker, but  the other hot, red, ran into the 40Amp dryer breaker! The dryer had one hot, black, running into the 40Amp dryer breaker and its other hot, red, running into the 50Amp stove breaker! The dryer outlet is 30Amp and the stove outlet is 50Amp. The dryer is listed as 30Amp requirement.

Any advice would be helpful on any portion of this,
Thank you!

[image][image][image]

Comment: Never switch wiring around while you are still amazed at how you found it.

Comment: Can you post photos of the subpanel in question please?

Comment: What problem were you trying to solve?  Make and model of panel and pics are needed. The changes you made probably ended up only supplying  120 to the dryer which powered the controls and motor, but not the heating element...your changes probably put both legs on the same phase....just a guess at this point without knowing more.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide clear pictures of the panel, and the **label** of the panel. Sounds like your breakers are **not** in the right spots to get 240v, since most (US/Canada) dryers use 120V for everything but the heating element. And I agree that changing things while you are amazed is *... a dubious choice.*

Comment: How tall is the box for your panel?

Comment: Is this a rental???

Comment: Painters....ugh.

Comment: Subpanel is 17” high

Answer (score 2):

One of the serious sparkys will know every detail about your panel, but it's obvious from the labeling that it has a pair on each phase, so the location of your 40 and 50 A dual breakers needs to shift down (or up, for the 40 that will be a 30 when you fix it right) by one space to actually supply 240V.

Which means someone highly unqualified has been working in this panel; there may be other problems I haven't spotted. That one is deer in the headlights blindingly obvious.

Comment: Per @Jack's comment, if this is a rental, close it up, step away, and call your landlord to call a licensed electrician - you can't work on it, your landlord can't work on it, it must be a licensed electrician - a principle which has clearly been violated at some point.

Comment: Besides, this panel is NFG anyway as the drywallers/painters splattered junk all over its innards!

Comment: Franklin also needs to identify any multi-wire branch circuits before moving breakers around.

Comment: The circuits in question both have their respective, separate neutrals.